# Minutes and seconds format

Tags: java

This is a little messy, but I'm trying to format a calculated time into a formatted display of

```
MM mins SS.sssssssss secs
```

for example:

```
08 mins 33.324423323 secs
```

Below I have my code, but one problem I keep reaching is that the seconds will sometimes be over 60, which is obviously wrong. As you can see, I have applied mod operation to the seconds, but that still isn't helping. I imagine I'm missing something minor.

FYI this method takes long as argument for nanoseconds and then converts that to minutes/seconds.

```
private static String printTime(long nanos){
    String time = "";
    double ms = ((double)nanos)/1000000;
    float nano = nanos;
    double sec = ms/1000;
    long min = (long)sec/60;

    nano %= 1000000000;
    nano /= 1000000000;
    sec %= 60;

    time = String.format("%02d mins %2.0f%9.9f secs",min,sec,nano);

    return time;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `nano %= 1000000000;` followed by `nano /= 1000000000` mean that `nano` will always be zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the floating point math. Stick to integers. Using floating point introduces the possibility of undesirable accuracy errors. With integers you don't have to deal with rounding a decimal places and all those headaches.

```
private static String printTime(long ticks) {
    long nano = ticks % 1000000000; ticks /= 1000000000;
    long sec  = ticks % 60;         ticks /= 60;
    long min  = ticks;

    return String.format("%02d mins %02d%09d secs", min, sec, nano);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code that I use to convert a String to a `Timestamp` which contaitains nanos.  The String in this situation is the representation of a long containing unix time including nanoseconds.

```
public static Timestamp convertToTimestamp(String in) {

    BigDecimal dt = new BigDecimal (in);
    BigDecimal remainder = dt.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE);
    dt = dt.subtract(remainder);
    dt = dt.scaleByPowerOfTen(3);

    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(dt.longValue());
    int nano = remainder.scaleByPowerOfTen(9).intValue();
    ts.setNanos(nano);
    return (ts);

}
```

I am sure that I stole this code from somewhere.